# can not start cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, bigdata, cassandra-cli

I have a problem of using Cassandra. when i trying cassandra/bin cassandra -f following exception:

```
INFO 10:50:18,090 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-schema_columns-KeyCache-b.db
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
Dumping heap to java_pid7545.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [105901433 bytes in 0.574 secs]
ERROR 10:50:18,668 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:394)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:355)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService$KeyCacheSerializer.deserialize(CacheService.java:352)
at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:119)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:267)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:411)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:383)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:314)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:268)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:474)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:226)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:394)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:355)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService$KeyCacheSerializer.deserialize(CacheService.java:352)
at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:119)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:267)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:411)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:383)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:314)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:268)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:474)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:226)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
Exception encountered during startup: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Cassandra 2.0 ubuntu 12.04

Thank you for your help in resolving this, in advance.

Comment: How much memory does the machine you are using have, is cassandra running inside a VM, what is your heap size / permgen size, is this error produced the 1st time you start cassandra, or does it appear after C* has been running for a while and you restart?

Comment: @LyubenTodorov my machine configuration is
ram 4GB,ubuntu 12.04,jdk 7,cassandra 2.0 and getting error when restart the cassandra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to decrease the size of your key cache in your cassandra.yaml.  But to get started again just:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the VM memory configurations in cassandra environment file

It is present in conf folder of cassandra "conf/cassandra-env.sh"